# Set Multiple constrains for JSON column in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

How to create a column to save json data and have constraints "strict" JSON and "with unique Keys"?

Below code works only when a single constraint is present, but errors out with two constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE NOTIFICATIONS
  ADD RECEIVER VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
    CONSTRAINT strict_json
      CHECK (RECEIVER IS JSON STRICT) ,
    CONSTRAINT unique_json_keys
      CHECK (RECEIVER IS JSON WITH UNIQUE KEYS);
```

`Error report - ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option 01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option" *Cause:     *Action:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the syntax diagrams closely, you will find that (1) your constraints are "inline constraints", and (2) when defining multiple constraints on a single column, they should **not** be separated by comma.

Drop the comma between the constraints and try again.

Comment: As per your anwser removed comma and it worked. `ALTER TABLE NOTIFICATIONS ADD RECEIVER VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR) CONSTRAINT strict_json CHECK (RECEIVER IS JSON STRICT AND RECEIVER IS JSON WITH UNIQUE KEYS);`

Comment: @YuvarajChitela - the modified ALTER STATEMENT you posted in your comment (above this one) isn't what I was suggesting. You didn't simply remove the comma - you consolidated the two CHECK constraints into a single one. There may be very good reasons to define those two CHECK constraints separately (perhaps in the future you will need to disable one of them while still keeping the other one enabled - you can't do that with your re-written constraint). You can do **that** by removing the comma from your original statement ***and nothing else***.